# 2 processes with the same name. How do I only end one of them?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a small "problem" windows has a system file that cant be killed csrss.exe but if there is another file named csrss.exe in a different folder and it is running, how do I end its process? All i would know about the file is it's location and name/size.. basic file info.

lol i answered my question with a question.. anyway i just wanted to say I dont want to kill the process of the system file csrss, i want to kill the process of a file who happens to have the same filename & process name. is it even possible?

Comment: Since it's a system process it probably has a PID lower than the process you want to kill

Comment: its a critical system process.why do you want to kill.i dont think it can be killed.

Comment: @CodeIgnoto You can kill it, you computer will just crash.

Comment: @xiaomao are you sure.i think you will get a unable to terminate exception

Comment: @CodeIgnoto It is possible. From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx, you can see "Notice that you can kill CSRSS.EXE and WINLOGON.EXE if you like. Your computer will get very angry at you, but you can do it. (Save you work first!)". If you don't believe me try. Also the question asks to kill a process named by that name, but not the system one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to end a process based on its `FileInfo` such as Size/Attributes/etc.... Then, this is possible! Here's a simple example

**Example**

```
int FileSize = 0; //This belongs to the process you would like to terminate
//Create the process csrss for every process with the name csrss
foreach (Process csrss in Process.GetProcessesByName("csrss"))
{ 
     FileInfo csrssFile = new FileInfo(csrss.StartInfo.FileName); //Get the properties of its file name
     if (csrssFile.Length == FileSize)
     {
         csrss.Kill(); //Terminate the process based on its file length (size)
     }

}
```

**Another Example**

```
int FileSize = 0;
Process[] RunningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process csrss in RunningProcesses)
{
     if (csrss.ProcessName == "csrss")
     {
          FileInfo csrssFile = new FileInfo(csrss.StartInfo.FileName);
          if (csrssFile.Length == FileSize)
          {
               csrss.Kill();
          }
     }
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying should kill the *csrss.exe* process, but you could check the main `ProcessModule.FileName` property that contains the full path to the executable if you want to find specific processes with the same name:

```
Process process = // Get your process here
process.Modules[0].FileName == "C:\\MyPath\csrss.exe";
```

Comment: No No people, I do not want to kill the original system file csrss, I want to kill the process of a file who has the same name. :)

Comment: @ace007 You should put this comment on the question, not the answer =) Also you could edit your question and clarify that.